# segmentation fault , Memory not being allocated

Tags: c

The code is as follows , Seems like nothing wrong with it at all. My gcc doesnt find alloc.h

```
print(node *q)
    39  {   
    40      node *p=q;
    41              do
    42      {
    43          printf("%d",p->n);
    44          if(p->ptr != NULL)
    45          p=p->ptr;   
    46          else
```

(gdb) p p
$1 = (node *) 0x0

And the code where memory is allocated is

```
    if(p== NULL)
    {
            p=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
            if(p== NULL)
                    printf("The malloc failed\n");
            p->n=num;
            p->ptr=NULL;
    }
```

When I run this in debugger there is no message of malloc failed.

Can anyone help.
Regards

Sraddha

```
    add(node **q)
    {
         node *p=*q;
         int num;
         printf("Enter the number you want to add");
         scanf("%d", &num);
         if(p== NULL)
         {
            p=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
            if(p== NULL)
                    printf("The malloc failed\n");
            p->n=num;
            p->ptr=NULL;
         }
    }
```

Comment: Is `p` passed in to the allocator function as an argument (of type `node *`) by any chance?

Comment: Could you edit your post to show the rest of that loop please, and also say where the segv occurs? And, as Mat suggests, also show the whole allocation function.

Comment: Yes p is declared as node *p;

Comment: The standard header where the prototype for `malloc()` is, is `<stdlib.h>`. You don't need "`alloc.h`" (whatever that is) ...

Comment: I have included stdlib.h

Comment: lIke the gdb output I show in the question.gdb) p p $1 = (node *) 0x0                                                                    The segmentation fault occurs at                                      (gdb) run
Starting program: /home/vaishali/linklist 
Enter 'n' when u want to stop7

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x08048583 in print (q=0x0) at linklist.c:42

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the issues addressed by hmjd's answer, you might want to consider a different program design. You have made function does three entirely different things: interaction with the user, allocation of memory and the actual algorithm. This program design was the actual culprit that caused the bug.

Instead, you might want to consider a more object-oriented approach:

```
int prompt_user (void) // this function interacts with the user ("GUI")
{
  int num;
  printf("Enter the number you want to add");
  scanf("%d", &num);
  getchar(); // discard line feed character from stdin

  return num;
}

void init_node (node* new_node, int num)
{
  new_node->n = num;
  new_node->ptr = NULL;
}


// this code is the caller:
{
  node* q = NULL;

  ...

  int num = prompt_user();

  if(q == NULL)
  {
    q = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(q == NULL)
    {
      // error handling
    }
  }  

  init_node(q, num);

  ...

  free(q);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to assign to `*q` in the `add()` function, not the local `p`:

```
add(node **q)
{
     int num;
     printf("Enter the number you want to add");
     scanf("%d", &num);
     if(*q == NULL)
     {
        *q = malloc(sizeof(node)); /* no need to cast return value. */

        /* Corrected if logic to not access failed malloc. */
        if(*q == NULL)
        {
            printf("The malloc failed\n");
        }
        else
        {
            *q->n=num;
            *q->ptr=NULL;
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Yes I realize now . Thanks hmjd . I ll try this.

Comment: The comment about malloc in this answer is important, [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565496/specifically-whats-dangerous-about-casting-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: hmjd , You were absolutely right , Yes I had failed to change the pointer to the queue head . Thanks very much.

Comment: Thanks I didnt know . :D Ok !